# Populate password field doesn't work by factory

Tags: mysql, laravel, factory, laravel-6

I'm latin so my english is not very good looking.

I'm trying to populeate my MySQL database using a Laravel factory class, I have a polimorphic many to many relationship between providers and provider users. This is my `UserFactory.php`:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/Bogota"));

    return [
        "name" => $faker->name(),
        "email" => $faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
        "password" => Hash::make("12345678"),
        "created_at" => $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        "updated_at" => $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ];
});

$factory->state(User::class, "provider-user", function(){
    return ["role_id" => config("static.role_ids.provider-user")];
});
```

And this is my `ProviderSeeder.php`:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(Provider::class, 10)
        ->state("natural")
        ->create()
        ->each(function($provider){

            $provider->users()->createMany(
                factory(User::class, rand(3, 6))
                    ->states("provider-user")
                    ->make()
                    ->toArray()
            );

            $provider->location()->save(
                factory(Location::class)
                    ->make(["owner_type" => "App\\Models\\Provider"])
            );
        });
}
```

I defined the relationship between the `Provider.php` and `User.php` models in the standard way. I have the `password` field of the `User.php` model set into the  `$hidden` array of the model class.

`ProviderFactory.php` and `LocationFactory.php` works fine but `UserFactory.php` doesn't. I'm getting a `General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value` when I try to seed my database tables but this error disapear when I remove the `password` field from the `$hidden` array of the `User.php` model, then everything works as expected.

I hope somebody could to help me with this information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are circumventing the factory, you are relying on the fillable guard and i would assume password is not fillable.

I would assume changing the code to use the factory and use save instead as you are not creating would help the problem.

```
$provider->users()->saveMany(
    factory(User::class, rand(3, 6))
        ->states("provider-user")
        ->create()
    );
```

Comment: I'm sorry @mrhn, the password attribute is fillable in my user model but if I use the code you suggest with the password hidden I get the same error message. Why you are saying I'm circumventing the factory ?

Comment: make does not save the data in the database but creates the model, when you save the relationship you use createMany therefor the relationship will create the model instead of the factory. If factory(User::class)->create() does not save a password, i would believe a listener getter setter is overwritten it as it should work.

Comment: I just did a code combination... ```$provider->users()->saveMany(factory(User::class, rand(3, 6))->states("provider-user")->make())```, @mrhn thank you for comment.